# Defining a Type to be a Superset of Types

Tags: c#, arrays, types

Suppose I have a basic inheritance structure:

```
public class Letter {...}
public class A : Letter {...}
public class B : Letter {...}
public class C : Letter {...}

public class Number {...} 
public class One : Number {...}
```

I want to define an array of `Type`s such that only `Type`s which inherit from `Letter` are valid. So a sample array might look like:

`(type)[] myArray = new (type)[] {typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C)};`

But the assignment

`myArray[0] = typeof(One);`

would fail. Is it possible to define such a structure?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is generics with constraints.

Comment: @Tim: mind it is not the *objects* that are stored, it are the `System.Type`s...

Comment: I don't think that the .NET type system can enforce that.

Comment: For sure it's possible, since you are allowed to write classes with indexers and put whatever logic you want inside. But it cannot be a plain array.

Comment: @Jon: I think the OP asks for a type-checkable solution (at compile time) for the problem. Evidently one can define a data structure that does checking at the frontdoor.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can it ever be statically verifiable when `Type` instances can be produced at runtime?

Comment: @Jon: that's my point exactly: it isn't. But you can check the type at runtime, or you could use code contracts and hope that it can be verified.

Comment: @Tim: You can do this with Java (although the check can be spoofed anyway), but in C# `System.Type` is not generic.

Comment: See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388964/how-can-i-inherit-the-string-class

Comment: @jdweng: what does this post has to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible that you can use *the type system* to enforce this: `typeof` returns an instance of [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is a generic class and there is no aspect of the typesystem that can enforce that only subtypes of a certain type can be stored. So *using* the typesystem for this is probably not the way to go.

There are some alternatives however:

1. You could use [*contract contracts*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and hope that your can verify this at compile time. For instance:

   ```
   Type[] myArray = new (type)[] {typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C)};

   //...

   Contract.Ensures(Contract. ForAll (myArray,t => typeof(Letter).IsAassignableFrom(t));
   ```

   Note however that it is an undecidable problem, and that the contract verifier can only give a conservative answer.
2. You could define a data-structure (probably a subset of an `ICollection<Type>` that enforces this at the front door. For instance:

   ```
   public class SubTypeList<T> : IList<Type> {

       private readonly List<Type> innerList = new List<Type>();

       public void Add (Type type) {
           if(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
               innerList.Add(type);
           } else {
               throw new ArgumentException("The given System.Type must be an inherit from T!");
           }
       }

       //Implement other methods
       //...

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

All types are instances of `System.Type`, being the same statically. Therefore, doing this using a conventional array is not possible. One option is to create a data structure that only allows addition through type parameters:

```
internal sealed class LetterTypeSet : IReadOnlyCollection<Type>
{
    readonly ISet<Type> types = new HashSet<Type>();
    public IEnumerator<Type> GetEnumerator() => this.types.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
    public int Count => this.types.Count;

    public bool Add<T>()
        where T : Letter
    {
        return this.types.Add(typeof (T));
    }
}
```

This would allow:

```
var letters = new LetterTypeSet();
letters.Add<A>(); //ok
letters.Add<B>(); //ok
letters.Add<One>(); //CS0311 "The type 'One' cannot be used ..."
```

Note: I'm using a `ISet<T>` as the underlying data structure, you may or may not want to use a `List<T>` instead depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define an array of `Letter`, and only `Letter` objects and types derived from it can be assigned to the elements. However, when you get an element of the array, the compiler will think it is a `Letter`. That may be what you want. If not, you can discover what it really is at run-time:

```
if (myArray[i] is A)
{
    A objA = myArray[i] as A;
    ...
```

The `is` and `as` operators are used in these downcasts to verify that the downcast is valid.

Or, better, you can define behavioral properties and methods of your `Letter` base class that allow the caller to obtain the behaviors of the derived classes without having to know what the exact class of the object is.

```
myArray[i].DrawSelf(Point ptStart)
```

and make the various derived classes responsible for knowing how to draw themselves starting at a given location.

Comment: I think you do not understand the problem correctly. `myArray` will contain `System.Type` **instances**, **not** instances of `Letter`.

Comment: Wrap your array in accessors that verify the `Type` instance meets the test `typeof(Letter).IsAssignableFrom(t)`.