# Encrypt/Decrypt property while writing/reading to c# mongo db

Tags: c#, mongodb, encryption, asp.net-core

Just going to lay out all the info i have:

In short, I am looking for something exactly (literally) like [this](https://www.compose.com/articles/encrypting-sensitive-data-in-your-mongodb-database) but compatible with ASP Core (2.2) and the C# MongoDB Driver (2.7).

This seems like such a common requirement, I am very surprised i can't find anything already built.

Here is what i have so far:

Model:

```
public class Patient
{
    //comes from the client as XXXXXXXXX, RegEx: "([0-9]{9})"
    //[MongoEncrypt]
    public EncryptedString SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }  
}
```

<s>Attribute:</s>

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MongoEncryptAttribute : BsonSerializerAttribute
{
    public MongoEncryptAttribute()
    {
        SerializerType = typeof(MongoEncryptSerializer);
    }
}
```

Custom Serializer:

```
public interface IMongoEncryptSerializer : IBsonSerializer<EncryptedString>{ }

public class MongoEncryptSerializer : SerializerBase<EncryptedString>, IMongoEncryptSerializer
{
    private readonly string _encryptionKey;

    public MongoEncryptSerializer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _encryptionKey = configuration.GetSection("MongoDb")["EncryptionKey"];
    }

    public override EncryptedString Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var encryptedString = context.Reader.ReadString();
        return AesThenHmac.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(encryptedString, _encryptionKey);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, EncryptedString value)
    {
        var encryptedString = AesThenHmac.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, _encryptionKey);
        context.Writer.WriteString(encryptedString);
    }
}
```

Open Items:

1. <s>Use DI (vanilla .net core DI) to get the Serializer. thinking of something like `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(type,serializer)` in a bootstrap method where i can access the service collection and do a `GetInstance` but then i would need `string SocialSecurityNumber` to use a custom type (maybe `SecureString`?)</s>

   - Went with a custom type,`EncryptedString`, with [implicit string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22912864/411094)
2. <s>Use DI in the serializer to get the key (initially from `IConfiguration`/`appsettings.json`</s>  and then ultimately from Azure KeyVault (whole new can of worms for me)) and the EncryptionProvider
3. deterministic encryption for searching. `AesThenHmac` comes from this popular [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/411094).  I can store and retrieve data back fine in its current implementation.  But in order to search for SSNs, I need deterministic encryption which this lib does not provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Solution:

Model:

```
public class Patient
{
    //comes from the client as XXXXXXXXX, RegEx: "([0-9]{9})"
    public EncryptedString SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }  
}
```

Custom Type:

```
public class EncryptedString
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public EncryptedString(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(EncryptedString s)
    {
        return s._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator EncryptedString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new EncryptedString(value);
    }
}
```

Serializer(using [Deterministic Encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68032/66687)):

```
public interface IEncryptedStringSerializer : IBsonSerializer<EncryptedString> {} 

public class EncryptedStringSerializer : SerializerBase<EncryptedString>, IEncryptedStringSerializer
{
    private readonly IDeterministicEncrypter _encrypter;
    private readonly string _encryptionKey;

    public EncryptedStringSerializer(IConfiguration configuration, IDeterministicEncrypter encrypter)
    {
        _encrypter = encrypter;
        _encryptionKey = configuration.GetSection("MongoDb")["EncryptionKey"];
    }

    public override EncryptedString Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var encryptedString = context.Reader.ReadString();
        return _encrypter.DecryptStringWithPassword(encryptedString, _encryptionKey);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, EncryptedString value)
    {
        var encryptedString = _encrypter.EncryptStringWithPassword(value, _encryptionKey);
        context.Writer.WriteString(encryptedString);
    }
}
```

Registering the serializer:

```
collection.AddScoped<IEncryptedStringSerializer, EncryptedStringSerializer>();
//then later...
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<EncryptedString>(sp.GetService<IEncryptedStringSerializer>());
```

Comment: Just to make things easier, you should add: 'public override string ToString() => $"{_value}";' to the EncryptedString class. Otherwise you will need to cast your EncryptedString whenever it is called upon. Your answer helped me with a project i'm currently working on - thanks for the effort here.